# Pyplot from pytrends not plotting correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am currently trying to plot a simple search trend using pytrends and pyplot. This code does display a graph and the correct line; however, it also presents a second line and I am unsure where it comes from. The picture can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yp9Pi.png) with the correct line in blue and the additional line in orange at the bottom. My code is as follows:

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
from matplotlib import  pyplot as plt

pytrends = TrendReq(hl='en')
trend = pytrends.build_payload(['tesla'])
interest = pytrends.interest_over_time()
plt.plot(interest)
plt.grid()
plt.title('Trend')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The graph displays this extra line because of the isPartial column, which displays a boolean value depending on whether or not the data for a given month is complete. Adding the line `del interest['isPartial']` will simply resolve the issue and present [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB8be.png) graph without the line representing the isPartial values. Altogether, the code will look like the following:

```
from matplotlib import  pyplot as plt
pytrends = TrendReq(hl='en')
trend = pytrends.build_payload(['tesla'])
interest = pytrends.interest_over_time()
del interest['isPartial']
plt.plot(interest)
plt.grid()
plt.title('Trend')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.show()
```